# PouchDB in Electron, set data storage location

Tags: electron, pouchdb

I am writing an Electron application that will need to store a large amount of data on the client. I want to use PouchDB but I need to have control over the location where the database is held on the user's PC. I can't find anything in the docs about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the location of the database is very simple.

```
db = new PouchDB(dbFilePath);
```

You can set the dbFilePath to the path that you want. For example, I want to set the path to where the Electron application runs. So I do the following.

```
const appDataDirectory = app.getPath('appData');
let dbFilePath = appDataDirectory + '/data/';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  dbFilePath = './data/';
}
log.debug('NODE_ENV:%s, dbFilePath:%s', process.env.NODE_ENV, dbFilePath);
let db = new PouchDB(dbFilePath);
```

Comment: @chrispytoes Did this not answer your question?